# Does a woman of the people of the book have to wear the Islamic headscarf during her marriage with a Muslim man?

Tags: nikah, hijab

Salam brothers and sisters.

I hope someone can answer this question: If a woman of the book is getting married to a Muslim man and the Nikah is going to be performed in the mosque with an Imam and 2 witnesses provided by the Imam, does the woman have to wear a headscarf given that she is not a Muslim?

What if she is struggling to wear a headscarf? (i.e unable to get it right without it falling off etc..)

Is it a requirement/obligation for her to wear the headscarf?

Thank you.

Comment: Rules for Muslims apply for Muslims and vice versa.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - thank you but not sure I follow? :)

Comment: She is not a Muslim she is not asked by our Shari'a to wear it. It could be an option for her to wear it by respect when in a mosque, but nothing more. If the people of the mosque insist or any other I'm afraid that would be against the rulings of Islam. However it could be an order based on her shari'a, but that isn't related to this site.

Answer (score 2):

The obligations of Islam doesn't apply to non-Muslims. Allah says in the Qur'an (what means):

> This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those
>   conscious of Allah -
>
> Who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We
>   have provided for them,
>
> And who believe in what has been revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and
>   what was revealed before you, and of the Hereafter they are certain
>   [in faith].
>
> Those are upon [right] guidance from their Lord, and it is those who
>   are the successful.
>
> [Qur'an 2:2 - 2:5]

It is clear from the above verses that the rules of the Qur'an only apply to Muslims. So, she has no obligation to wear it. If she voluntarily wears it, (as a show of respect) then there is nothing wrong with that.